lme4: how to specify a correlations of 0 between random effects (i.e., slopes and intecepts; in the output: Corr = 0)
As a follow up question to Dr. Bolker's answer:
I am encountering a similar challenge in my analysis. My goal is to set the correlation between my random effects to be 0, specifically between the random slope and intercept.
However, I'm finding that this results in a correlation of 1.00 between the random effects (I am getting a warning of boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')).
Could you kindly point out if there's an aspect I might be overlooking or if there's an alternative approach I should consider?
Thank you very much for your time and assistance!
My simulated data was generated from:
N <-  500 # sample size
n_clinic <-  50 # number of clusters
MT <- rep(c(0,1), length.out= N) # setting dichotomous predictor: control vs. treat
clinic = rep(1:n_clinic, each = N/n_clinic) # defining cluster ID
ppt_ID <- seq_len(N) # (optional) defining ppt ID
intercept <-  10 # grand mean
MTeffect <- 0 # overall, fixed effect
sigma <-  5 # variability within cluster
sd_int <-  5 # variability in intercepts
sd_MT <-  0 # (no) variability in cluster-specific coefficients
cor <-  0 # (no) association between intercepts and slopes
# var-covar matrix for slopes and intercepts

#set.seed(311)
# var-covar matrix for slopes and intercepts
varmat <-  matrix(c(sd_int^2, cor, cor, sd_MT^2), 2, 2) 
# generate data from var-covar
re <-  mvtnorm::rmvnorm(n_clinic, sigma = varmat)
colnames(re) = c('Intercept', 'MTeffect')
# generate outcome variable
ment_health <-  (intercept + re[clinic, 'Intercept']) + 
          (MTeffect + re[clinic, 'MTeffect'])*MT + rnorm(N, sd = sigma)
# putting everthing together
dat <-  tibble(
    ment_health,
    MT = factor(MT),
    clinic,
    ppt_ID
  )

It is purposefully set with a SD of slopes at 0. (I know this might look silly, but the idea is to draw a random sample from a population which does not truly has a varying slopes, and I it to be clear).
I tired the following
mod <- lme4::lmer(ment_health ~ MT + (1 + MT || clinic), data = dat)

I expected to see Corr of 0 in the output from summary(mod). But, instead I see Corr of 1.00.
I also know how to do this with glmmTMB (and it works), but I need to use lme4 specifically.
Any advice or insight will be hugly appreciated!

The correlation of 1 you see isn't it estimating the correlation at 1, but instead it is failing to be able to estimate the correlation (hence the singular fit). However, I've tried both syntaxes for dropping the correlation entirely (MT||clinic) and (1|clinic) + (0+MT|clinic) and it keeps trying to estimate the correlation. Maybe this is a bug?

@sjp, it may be an "infelicity", but it's not a bug. It has to do with how factors are converted to model matrices.

As documented in ?lmer::lmer

(Because of the way it is implemented, the ‘||’-syntax works only for design matrices containing numeric (continuous) predictors; to fit models with independent categorical effects, see dummy or the lmer_alt function from the afex package.)

So here are three ways to fit the model:
convert the factor variable back to numeric
(as.numeric(dat$MT)-1 or as.numeric(as.character(dat$MT)) would both get us back to a 0/1 numeric variable)
dat$MTnum <- as.numeric(dat$MT)-1
mod2 <- lme4::lmer(ment_health ~ MT + (1 + MTnum || clinic), data = dat)
VarCorr(mod2)

use the dummy() function to derive a 0/1 variable
mod3 <- lme4::lmer(ment_health ~ MT + (1 + lme4::dummy(MT, "1") || clinic), data = dat)
VarCorr(mod3)

use afex::lmer_alt
mod4 <- afex::lmer_alt(ment_health ~ MT + (1 + MT || clinic), data = dat)
VarCorr(mod4)

The last option would be most convenient if you had a factor with more than two levels (otherwise you'd have to construct a dummy variable for every non-baseline level of the factor).

Thank you very much @benbolker ! Though, when I use these methods with lme4, I don't get an estimate of Corr - it simply doesn't appear in the output. Does this mean it is constrained to 0?
Thank you again, I really appreciate you taking the time!

Yes, that's what it means.
